# No such property: getToHour for class: OutagePolicyScript

Tags: groovy

I 've continously getting error:

> 2019-05-06 14:37:40,128 [EPI-TaskExecutor-1] ERROR
>   ScriptExecutionExceptionHandler.handleScriptError(31) - Script with id
>   [3e2fd082-62f3-46a2-8fca-71b1f9cef028] and label [Outage definition
>   script] reports an error: : No such property: getToHour for class:
>   OutagePolicyScript.

Outages.xml file is OK, and is placed together with outage.dtd file in correct location.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import com.hp.opr.api.scripting.Event;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

class OutagePolicyScript
{   
    Object syncObject = new Object();
    final static String fileName = "/opt/HP/BSM/Temp/outages.xml";      // for Windows it will be: "d:/HPBSM/Temp/outages.xml";
    final static Log s_log = LogFactory.getLog("com.hp.opr.epi.OutagePolicyScript");
    List<OutageDefinition> outageDefinitions = new ArrayList<OutageDefinition>();
    Thread loadXMLThread;
    final boolean isSuppressEventsOrClose = true;

def init()
{
    LoadOutagesFromXML r1 = new LoadOutagesFromXML();
    loadXMLThread = new Thread(r1);
    loadXMLThread.start();

    s_log.debug("init finished");
}

def destroy()
{
    s_log.debug("going to stop thread....");
    loadXMLThread.interrupt();
}

def process(List<Event> events)
{           
    synchronized(syncObject) {
        try
        {
            events.each {Event event ->                     
                handleEventSuppressionIfNeeded(event, "EST");
                //event.setTitle("Modified by CA/EPI: " + event.getTitle());

                // always include following check for each event
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    throw new InterruptedException()
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            s_log.error("process of events interrupted", e);
        }
    }
}    

private void handleEventSuppressionIfNeeded(Event event, String timezoneId) 
{
    // Calculate if event was received during the accepted time window.    
    Date timeRecieved = event.getTimeReceived();
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timezoneId);
    if (tz != null)
        cal = Calendar.getInstance(tz);
    cal.setTime(timeRecieved);

    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int dow = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);        

    //event.addCustomAttribute("hour", Integer.toString(hour));
    //event.addCustomAttribute("minute", Integer.toString(minute));
    //event.addCustomAttribute("day of week", Integer.toString(dow));

    // go over all the outage definitions, and compare event attributes to the rule
    outageDefinitions.each {OutageDefinition outage ->
        if (outage.getIsActive()) {
            s_log.debug("Checking active rule: " + outage.getDescription());
            // check if the event's day of week is one of the outage definition days. in case the rule cross day, reduce 1 for day of week
            if (ArrayUtils.contains(outage.getDays(), dow) || (outage.getCrossDay() && ArrayUtils.contains(outage.getDays(), (dow == 1) ? 7 : dow-1 ))) {
                // check if event hour and minute are inside rule's from/to
                // convert all configurations to minutes
                // if the rule cross a day, then add to "to" 24 hours in order to compare from <= event_time < to
                // if the rule cross a day AND event hour < "from" then it means the event is in the next day and need to add 24 hours too
                int eventTimeInMin = ((hour < outage.getFromHour() && outage.getCrossDay()) ? hour + 24 : hour) * 60 + minute;
                int fromInMin = outage.getFromHour() * 60 + outage.getFromMinute();
                int toInMin = (outage.getCrossDay() ? outage.getToHour() + 24 : outage.getToHour) * 60 + outage.getToMinute();                                      

                if (eventTimeInMin >= fromInMin && eventTimeInMin < toInMin) {
                    s_log.debug("event time is within this outage rule, proceed to compare event's attributes");
                    boolean foundMatch = true;
                    Set<String> attributeNames = outage.getAttributesList().keySet();
                    attributeNames.each {String name ->
                        boolean attMatchResult;
                        // at the moment, all comparisons are using "EQ"                            
                        switch (name) {
                            case "title" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRuleForcontains("title", event.getTitle(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            case "application" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRule("application", event.getApplication(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            case "object" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRule("object", event.getObject(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            case "category" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRule("category", event.getCategory(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            case "subcategory" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRule("subcategory", event.getSubCategory(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            case "nodeHint" : attMatchResult = compareEventAttributeToOutageRuleForcontains("nodeHint", event.getNodeHints().getHint(), outage.getAttributesList().get(name)); break;
                            default : s_log.error("attribute name [" + name + "] from outages.xml is not supported");
                        }
                        s_log.debug("result for attribute [" + name + "] is: " + attMatchResult);
                        foundMatch &= attMatchResult;
                    }
                    s_log.debug("result after processing all attributes in the rule is: " + foundMatch);
                    if (foundMatch) {
                        if (isSuppressEventsOrClose)
                            event.addCustomAttribute("SuppressDueToOutageRule", outage.getDescription());
                        else
                            event.setState(LifecycleState.CLOSED);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    s_log.debug("Current rule doesnt match for the event's time, this rule will be skipped");                   
                }
            }
            else {
                s_log.debug("Current rule doesnt match for the event's day, this rule will be skipped");                    
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean compareEventAttributeToOutageRule(String eventAttName, String eventAttValue, Set<String> ruleValues) 
{               
    if (ruleValues.contains(eventAttValue)) {
        s_log.debug("found match on attribute [" + eventAttName + "], attribute value=" + eventAttValue);
        return true;
    }
    // else, no match
    s_log.debug("no match for attribute " + eventAttName);
    return false;
}

private boolean compareEventAttributeToOutageRuleForcontains(String eventAttName, String eventAttValue, Set<String> ruleValues) 
{               
    Iterator<String> itr = ruleValues.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (eventAttValue.indexOf(itr.next()) != -1) {  // check if the event attribute contains the rule's value
            s_log.debug("found match on attribute [" + eventAttName + "], attribute value=" + eventAttValue);
            return true;            
        }
    }

    // else, no match
    s_log.debug("no match for attribute " + eventAttName);
    return false;
}

class LoadOutagesFromXML implements Runnable 
{
    long lastModifiedTime = -1;

    public void run() 
    {
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            s_log.debug("in running.... current time: " + new Date());
            // lock the sync object
            synchronized(syncObject) {
                long before = System.currentTimeMillis();                   
                readOutageFile();
                long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
                s_log.debug("Loading outages definitions from XML took [" + (after - before) + "] ms.");
            }
            Thread.sleep(60000);    // 60 seconds
        }
        s_log.debug("thread interrupted....");
    }

    private void readOutageFile()
    {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();                  
            File f = new File(fileName);
            if (f.lastModified() == lastModifiedTime) {
                // the file wasnt changed, no need to reload file
                s_log.debug("file LastModifiedTime didn't change, no need to reload configuration");
                return;
            }
            // otherwise, clear previous results and reload XML file
            outageDefinitions.clear();
            s_log.debug("going to load outage.xml");
            Document doc = db.parse(f);
            NodeList outages = doc.getElementsByTagName("outage");
            for (int i=0 ; i<outages.getLength() ; ++i) {
                s_log.debug("handle outage: " + Integer.toString(i));
                // going to handle specific outage definition
                Element aOutage = (Element)outages.item(i);
                Element aTimeWindow = (Element)(aOutage.getElementsByTagName("timeWindow").item(0));            
                outageDefinitions.add(new OutageDefinition(aOutage.getAttribute("description"), 
                                                            aOutage.getAttribute("isEnabled"), 
                                                            aTimeWindow.getElementsByTagName("days").item(0).getTextContent(),
                                                            parseIntFromStr(aTimeWindow.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent(), true),
                                                            parseIntFromStr(aTimeWindow.getElementsByTagName("from").item(0).getTextContent(), false),
                                                            parseIntFromStr(aTimeWindow.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent(), true),
                                                            parseIntFromStr(aTimeWindow.getElementsByTagName("to").item(0).getTextContent(), false),
                                                            parseAttributesFromXML((Element)aOutage.getElementsByTagName("eventsFilter").item(0))));
            }
            lastModifiedTime = f.lastModified();
            s_log.debug("Going to keep lastModifiedTime as " + lastModifiedTime);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            s_log.error("caught exception during parsing of outage.xml", e);
            lastModifiedTime = -1;
        }   
    }

    private int parseIntFromStr(String str, boolean isHour) 
    {
        String[] array = str.trim().split(":");
        if (array.length != 2) {
            s_log.debug("Bad time format, expect HH:MM format but recieved: " + str);
            return -1;
        }
        if (isHour)
            return Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
        else
            return Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
    }

    private Map<String, Set<String>> parseAttributesFromXML(Element eventsFilter)
    {
        Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
        NodeList eventAttributes = eventsFilter.getElementsByTagName("eventAttribute");
        for (int i=0 ; i<eventAttributes.getLength() ; ++i) {
            NodeList attributeValues = eventAttributes.item(i).getElementsByTagName("value");
            Set<String> values = new HashSet<String>(attributeValues.getLength());
            for (int j=0 ; j<attributeValues.getLength() ; j++) {           
                values.add(attributeValues.item(j).getTextContent());
            }           
            result.put(eventAttributes.item(i).getAttribute("name"), values);
        }       
        return result;
    }
}

class OutageDefinition 
{
    String description;
    boolean isActive;
    int[] days;
    int fromHour;
    int fromMinute;
    int toHour;
    int toMinute;
    boolean crossDay;
    Map<String, Set<String>> attributesList;

    public OutageDefinition(String desc, String active, String outageDays, int oFromHour, int oFromMinute, int oToHour, int oToMinute, Map<String, Set<String>> oAttributes) {
        this.description = desc;
        this.isActive = Boolean.parseBoolean(active);           
        this.fromHour = oFromHour;
        this.fromMinute = oFromMinute;
        this.toHour = oToHour;
        this.toMinute = oToMinute;
        this.attributesList = oAttributes;
        this.crossDay = false;
        // check if time cross a day
        if (this.fromHour > this.toHour) {
            s_log.debug("in rule [" + this.description + "] found time condition that crosses midnight, adjust toHour accordingly");                
            this.crossDay = true;
        }

        this.days = getDaysFromString(outageDays);
    }

    private int[] getDaysFromString(String str) 
    {       
        String[] days = str.trim().split(",");
        int[] result = new int[days.length];        
        for (int i=0 ; i<days.length ; ++i) {               
            switch (days[i]) {
                case "Sunday" : result[i] = 1; break;
                case "Monday" : result[i] = 2; break;
                case "Tuesday" : result[i] = 3; break;
                case "Wednesday" : result[i] = 4; break;
                case "Thursday" : result[i] = 5; break;
                case "Friday" : result[i] = 6; break;
                case "Saturday" : result[i] = 7; break;
                default : result[i] = -1; break;
            }           
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public boolean getIsActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public int[] getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public int getFromHour() {
        return fromHour;
    }

    public int getFromMinute() {
        return fromMinute;
    }

    public int getToHour() {
        return toHour;
    }

    public int getToMinute() {
        return toMinute;
    }

    public Map<String, Set<String>> getAttributesList() {
        return attributesList;
    }

    public boolean getCrossDay() {
        return crossDay;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at this line. You must either call a method (`outage.getToHour()`) or access a property (`outage.getToHour`), but here you do both things. Choose what is correct

```
int toInMin = (outage.getCrossDay() ? outage.getToHour() + 24 : outage.getToHour) * 60 + outage.getToMinute();
```

Comment: You were rigth. Thank you very much. I really appriciate this.

Comment: @MatejVdovic actually, your IDE should be able to highlight such compiler errors. What IDE do you use?

Comment: this was script provided from vendor but it did not worked. Vendor said that they tested it but as you can see there was an error. I've tested now in eclipse and I can see what did you mean by 'able to highlight such compiler errors'. In future I'll do that first. I'm not programer and I only use vi for scripting.